# Protecting from SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sql-injection, pyrocms

I know the below code is open to injection but I am unsure what the best way to resolve it. Would it be best to repeat the `$new_id` line or is there something more that should be done?

**Controller:**

```
public function ajax_update_product_youtube()
{
    if($_POST)
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $new_id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['new_id']));
        $table = SITE_REF.'_ps_products';
        if($new_id != "")
        {
            $this->Ps_products_model->update_product_youtube($table, $id, $new_id);
        }                           
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function update_product_youtube($table, $id, $new_id)
    {
        $table = $this->_table_products;
        $this->db->query("
            UPDATE $table SET $table.youtube='$new_id' WHERE $table.id='$id'
        ");
    }
```

Comment: Switch to MySQLi or PDO and use prepared statements with bound parameters.

Comment: Also, if your id is always numeric, force it into an integer `$id = intval($_POST['id']);` and then check with `empty()` instead of `$new_id == ""`

Comment: @Revent But is there anything else that can be done to prevent injection - Yes is always an ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CodeIgniter's Active Record (Query Builder as of 3.0), or use query bindings.

**Active Record:**

```
$this->db->where('id', $id)->update($table, array('youtube' => $new_id));
```

**Query Bindings:**

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE {$table} SET youtube = ? WHERE id = ?", array($new_id, $id));
```

You should also:

- Never trust user input. Verify and sanitize before it ever reaches a DB query.
- Not make the table name dynamic like this. While nothing technically "wrong" with doing that, it gives yourself more work. Don't repeat yourself, keep things simple.